# How I can access to a returned data of a function with use the reflect package?

Tags: go

I have a function of the IndexController type:

```
func (this IndexController) ActionIndex() map[string]string {
    return map[string]string{"Name": "Hello from the actionIndex()!"}
}
```

It is used so:

```
routerInstance := router.Constructor(request)

controllerObject := controllers[routerInstance.GetRequestController(true)]

outputData := reflect.ValueOf(controllerObject).MethodByName(routerInstance.GetRequestAction(true)).Call([]reflect.Value{})

fmt.Println(outputData)
```

Now for example, how to show the **Name** element of **outputData**? I try to print so:

```
fmt.Println(outputData["Name"])
```

But program will exit with error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./server.go:28: non-integer array index "Name"
```

I will be thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [`(v Value) Call(…)`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call) returns a `[]reflect.Value`, so you need to index it to get your actual return value:

```
outputData := reflect.ValueOf(controllerObject).MethodByName(routerInstance.GetRequestAction(true)).Call([]reflect.Value{})[0]
```

(note the `[0]` at the end of the line)

From there on, you could probably do a type switch or maybe an interface conversion like `outputData.(map[string]interface{})` to get a map that you can index by string.

It would help though if you would provide your entire `server.go` file, or maybe put it up on [play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org).

Comment: I have found a solution. We must use `outputData.Interface().(map[string]string)`.